# C#: Thread.Sleep Not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, audio

I have a bit of code which is meant to show a form for a period of time and play a sound.
However the Form stays open.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer();
        ShowImage(@"Resources\Fish.png", "Fish", 256, 256, 1000);
        sp.SoundLocation = @"Resources\fish.wav";
        sp.Play();

    }


    public static void ShowImage(string img, string title, int width, int height, int timeout)
    {
        ImageContainer ic = new ImageContainer();
        ic.imgView.Image = Image.FromFile(img);
        ic.Text = title;
        ic.Size = ic.imgView.Image.Size;
        ic.Height = height;
        ic.Width = width;
        ic.ShowDialog();
        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        ic.Hide();
        ic.Opacity = 0;
        ic.Dispose();
    }
```

It just stays with the form open doesn't close or hide.
ImageContainer is a Form with a PictureBox called imgView in it.
I need it to time out for 1 second before it closes.

Comment: The ShowDialog() call is waiting for you to close the window.  You'll need a Timer whose Tick event handler calls the Close() method.  Which requires calling Application.Run().  You are going to get into trouble with this kind of code, you'll need to read a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
ic.ShowDialog();
```

Causes the form to show in a modal fashion, so that method blocks and prevents everything else from running until the form closes.

Change that line to:

```
ic.Show();
```

This is non-modal, and the rest of the method will complete.

Answer (score 1):

ShowDialog() is modal and never returns until you close the dialog.  You want Show(), and also you probably want to send a timer message to yourself instead of sleeping.

Some sample code here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/A_Custom_Message_Box.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sleep never gets called when you call `showdialog()` the form causes the calling thread to wait until the code in the form closes the window.  close the window with code in your form and things will work more like you expect.